# How do i put the desktop shortcut with the rest of the system folders on the folder sidebar?

Tags: directory

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The only help i could find is people saying i need to drag it to the side and make a new bookmark. This does not put desktop below home where it should be. I did not remove it on accident. I just installed ubuntu 22 and it came this way. I can not drag "desktop" up to where it goes and can find no options to arrange this. Where is the setting that decides what is listed there? Or, how do i "change the source of Nautilus" as suggested, without directions, below?

[image]

Comment: I guess that is what GNOME developers decided, and you cannot change it unless you change the source of Nautilus.

Comment: I had commented in another question of yours, that this may be a GNOME specific issue (Nautilus is GNOME's native file manager). The file managers in KDE (Dolphin), XFCE (Thunar) or MATE (Caja) allow you to make a lot more customizations. GNOME developers often hardcode their own choices, and they cannot be customized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this while solving a different problem. Chat GPT gave me the answer.

"Switch to Xorg:

Log out of your current session.
Before logging back in, click on the gear/cogwheel icon on the login screen.
Choose "Ubuntu on Xorg" or a similar option that uses Xorg instead of Wayland."